# Debug pause doesn't work in Xcode

Tags: xcode

For some reason, pause doesn't work anymore in Xcode when I debug my Objective-C++ Unit Tests for my project. The button looks active but nothing happens when I click on it.

Has anyone experienced similar issue before?

Xcode 8.2.1, macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 4):

**Disable** *Gather coverage data* from the scheme (Edit scheme → Test → Info → *Gather coverage data*).